# Rotate ZoomControls, but "No resource identifier found for attribute in package 'android'"

Tags: android, api, resources, libraries, identifier

I'm looking to rotate the ZoomControls widget. The API docs says that it inherits the 'android:rotation' attribute from android.view.View, yet Eclipse throws an error stating that it can't find the resource identifier when I add it in. What am I missing here?

Comment: A view attribute is not a resource identifier. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Is your project set to target API 11?

Comment: @Ted Hopp I've described what I wanted to do in the question. I want to rotate the ZoomControls 90 degrees to it appears vertically rather than the default horizontal layout. This does not appear to work when the min SDK is 2.3

@bigstones Thanks, this appears to make Eclipse not throw up compile errors, however, the widget still does not rotate.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this post is slightly old, but in case other people are having the same problem here goes...

The problem was most likely (as hinted by @bigstones) due to the fact that android:rotation calls the [setRotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29). As can be seen in the link, this was actually added in API level 11. When creating a new project Android API is set by default to API 8.

Solution: Just go to your project properties and change the API level to be anything above or equal to 11.

cheers